# ViewModel of a fragment

Tags: android, mvvm, viewmodel

I am trying to create ViewModel of a fragment and inside the constructor of ViewModel I need to pass Application but I am not to figure out how to do this can someone please help.
Thank you.

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private CodeDetailsViewModel codeDetailsViewModel;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        codeDetailsViewModel =
                new ViewModelProvider(this, new ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory(/*application*/)).get(CodeDetailsViewModel.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        return root;
    }
}
```

Comment: did you tried `getApplication()` ?

Comment: Why are you passing any specific factory at all instead of leaving it out and using the default (which uses `AndroidViewModelFactory` already)?

Answer (score 0):

If `CodeDetailsViewModel` extends `AndroidViewModel` then the constructor will receive the `Application`. See:  https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/AndroidViewModel.